# Can i use sumo or veins to send real data?

Tags: veins, sumo

I am in the process of creating a simulated scenario to test the amount of data a RSU can receive at any given time. I have real world CANbus data and would like to simulate a vehicle sending this data to the RSU. For example, simulate a vehicle sending one line of data per second from a file stored on my local PC, and then simulate 100, 200, 300 vehicles transmitting this data. Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. Encode your source data according to the frame format you wan to simulate (e.g., that used by BSMs), deduce the frame size in bits, then configure your cars to send messages of that size. For inspiration, try out the Veins tutorial example. Here, all cars send messages of the same size, but you can easily see where this is set.

Comment: Ok great, thank you. I have tried veins and it looks great. I am hoping to incorporate veins into my project.

Comment: Hi Christoff. So if i want to change the message format, do i alter the TraciDemo11p file and the BSM file? I really just need to send a file of, lets say 1kb, every second from the cars only to the RSU. Are there other files i need to make changes on too?Thank you

Comment: If all you want to send is "some data" worth 1kb, I suggest starting with <https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/traci/MyVeinsApp.cc> as a skeleton. It can use `populateWSM` of its base class to create messages of a desired size (see <https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc#L176>). What data/information the message is meant to represent does not matter to the simulation (and is totally independent from its simulated length)